# Table widget problems in python

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm basically trying to search an array and populate a table widget with the results of the search. Everything else seems to be working but when i execute my code and fill in all of the information I keep getting an error message that says TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str.  this is the code that I'm having the problem with

```
if(studentRecord['Student Name'] == self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()):
    studentsArray = self.loadstudentArrayOfRecords()
    self.ui.DetailstableWidget.insertRow(0)
    self.ui.DetailstableWidget.setItem(0,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(studentsArray[self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()]['Student Name']))
    self.ui.DetailstableWidget.setItem(0,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(studentsArray[self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()]['Student Code']))
    self.ui.DetailstableWidget.setItem(0,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(studentsArray[self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()]['Instrument Name']))
    self.ui.DetailstableWidget.setItem(0,3,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(studentsArray[self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()]['Instrument Code']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

`self.loadstudentArrayOfRecords()` should return a dict of dicts, but returns a dict of lists.

Check function `self.loadstudentArrayOfRecords()`.

You would find the bug faster if you made the code more readable:

```
searchText = self.ui.SearchlineEdit.text()
if studentRecord['Student Name'] == searchText:
    studentsArray = self.loadstudentArrayOfRecords()
    student = studentsArray[searchText]
    tableWidget = self.ui.DetailstableWidget
    tableWidget.insertRow(0)
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(student['Student Name']))
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(student['Student Code']))
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(student['Instrument Name']))
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(student['Instrument Code']))
```

Comment: Ive tried what you have suggested but the same problem is still happening, could you possibly explain to me how to return a dict of dicts rather than a dict of lists?

Comment: You should show us the code from function `self.loadstudentArrayOfRecords()` and the full exception traceback (after making the changes i suggested). Also, it looks like you lack debugging skills, so pay attention how people do this. Splitting the code across the lines helps debugging - you find out at which line precisely the code breaks. Also try printing variables before/after the line which uses them.

Comment: @user1236314 - Because you were doing so much on one line at a time, it makes it hard for you to know where the error is. Doing what warwaruk suggested will now give you a traceback that tells you the line with the error and you should be able to easily see what that problem is. If the traceback is telling you that `studentsArray` is the issue, then the result of `loadstudentArrayOfRecords()` is a list and you need to access it with int indexes. If it says a `student` line is the error, then that is the actual list. Basically you are confusing your data types somewhere.